# Does github api provide a way to get user's URL?

Tags: github, web-scraping, github-api

For example, for user:`django`, the url I want to retrieve thru github-api is not

```
https://github.com/django
```

but

```
http://www.djangoproject.com/
```

as shown below in the red ellipse:

[image]

The user search api does not return this url in the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Data that returns from the service would be as follows:

https://api.github.com/users/django

```
{
  "public_gists": 0,
  "type": "Organization",
  "followers": 240,
  "login": "django",
  "created_at": "2008-10-06T19:43:18Z",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/django",
  "avatar_url": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/fd542381031aa84dca86628ece84fc07?d=https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.github.com%2Fimages%2Fgravatars%2Fgravatar-org-420.png",
  "company": null,
  "email": null,
  "blog": "http://www.djangoproject.com/",
  "following": 0,
  "name": "Django",
  "location": "Internet",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/django",
  "id": 27804,
  "public_repos": 49
}
```

As you can see, that URL is in the blog field.